# what is player controller and auto posses?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have read that player controller is a class which gives input to pawn but it was also written that input facility can also be added directly into pawn class.I have few question 1)so what is the use of player controller? 2) can my game run without any player controller? 3)what is auto posses?( read in forum that only that pawn will move which is auto possessed but i didn't understood the concept) 4)what is default player controller? 5)how many player controller can i have in a level?

I am a noob and recently started learning ue4. so if any of my questions is invalid then sorry for that.please clarify my concept of player controller. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1)so what is the use of player controller?
- Player Controller class is the parent class that you can inherent any controller class from it to your players , where you setup all the logic related to your controls , mouse input, keyboard input, joystick...etc

2) can my game run without any player controller?
- No you cant , unreal engine will not you do this, bec by default, unreal engine assign a default player control class , thats how you able to navigate inside your game once you hit play at first time you hit play inside the editor for empty level .

3)what is auto posses? 
 - its how engine assign your control on playable character , lets say you have 2 character in the map, one driving the car and one carry the gun , and you want to switch between them and take the control on them, thats how Possesing work, but setting it auto, will assign you directly to default mainplayer class . read this document [Posses Pawns](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Gameplay/HowTo/PossessPawns) [PossessPawns/Blueprints](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Gameplay/HowTo/PossessPawns/Blueprints)

4)what is default player controller?
 - Its just as you read it, its the default player controller class , you dont use it, you do your own player class where its parent are Default player controller

5)how many player controller can i have in a level?
 - Depends on how many players "Types" you want at your level , bec you just do the player controller class , then just instances will be used by different players.

Really I suggest you learn through epic games resources video .
[Epic Games Academy](https://academy.unrealengine.com/)
and this course is awesome too
[Udemy Unreal Engine Course](https://www.udemy.com/unrealcourse/)